# Python: Merge two list of diferent objects by attribute

Tags: python

I'm trying to find an efficient way to merge two list of python objects (classes) with diferent structures and merge them into a new list of new object. The code:

```py
from datetime import datetime


class StructureOne(object):
    def __init__(self, date_time: datetime, name: str):
        self.date_time: datetime = date_time
        self.name: str = name
        self.value = None

    def set_value(self,value:float):
        self.value = value


class StructureTwo(object):
    def __init__(self, date_time: datetime, value: float):
        self.date_time = date_time
        self.value: float = value


def merge_lists(list_one: list[StructureOne], list_two: list[StructureTwo]) -> list[StructureOne]:
    for element_one in list_one:
        i = 0
        while i < len(list_two) and element_one.value is None:
            if element_one.date_time == list_two[i].date_time:
                element_one.set_value(value=list_two[i].value)
            i += 1
    return list_one


list_one: list[StructureOne] = [
    StructureOne(date_time=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0), name='zero'),
    StructureOne(date_time=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 1), name='one'),
    StructureOne(date_time=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 2), name='two'),
    StructureOne(date_time=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 3), name='three'),
]

list_two: list[StructureTwo] = [
    StructureTwo(date_time=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0), value=0),
    StructureTwo(date_time=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 1), value=1),
    StructureTwo(date_time=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 2), value=2),
    StructureTwo(date_time=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 3), value=3),
]


merged_list: list[StructureOne] = merge_lists(list_one=list_one, list_two=list_two)
```

The desired result is

```py
list_one: list[StructureOne] = [
    StructureOne(date_time=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0), name='zero', value=0),
    StructureOne(date_time=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 1), name='one', value=1),
    StructureOne(date_time=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 2), name='two', value=2),
    StructureOne(date_time=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 3), name='three', value=3),
]
```

We are trying to not use external libraries like [py-linq](https://github.com/viralogic/py-enumerable).

Comment: The current implementation of your `merge_lists` method simply returns`list_one`, as your set `value = None` and never alter its value.

Comment: what is your desired output? how are you going to resolve the mismatch in the dates? you are only interested in adding the `value` from `list_two` to the elements in `list_one`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- The lists might not be sorted.
- The `date_time` field is unique within each list.
- It is okey if the output is sorted.
- You want to populate the `value` of the objects in `list_one` with the `value` from the objects in `list_two` on matching `date_time`.
- You only want to populate the `value` of an object in `list_one` if it is `None`.
- In your code, you only populate the `value` if it is `not None`; I assume that you want to do the opposite.

```py
def merge_lists(list_one: list[StructureOne], list_two: list[StructureTwo]) -> list[StructureOne]:

    # sort lists by date_time
    list_1 = sorted(list_one, key=lambda x: x.date_time)
    list_2 = sorted(list_two, key=lambda x: x.date_time)

    # merge sort
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < len(list_1) and j < len(list_2):
        if list_1[i].date_time < list_2[j].date_time:
            i += 1
        elif list_1[i].date_time > list_2[j].date_time:
            j += 1
        else:
            # date_time matches
            # populate value from list_two into list_one if value is None
            if list_1[i].value is None:
                list_1[i].value = list_2[j].value
            i += 1
            j += 1

    return list_1
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to change the `value` attribute of `StructureOne` to the `value` of `StructureTwo` in the order of each list then you can do this to modify the elements in `list_one`:

```
for elem_one, elem_two in zip(list_one,list_two):
    elem_one.value = elem_two.value
```

You don't even need to have the `value` attribute in `StructureOne`, it will work the same:

```
class StructureOne(object):
    def __init__(self, date_time: datetime, name: str):
        self.date_time: datetime = date_time
        self.name: str = name
```

If by merging you mean to get rid of `list_two` you can delete the variable so it will get discarded.

```
del list_two
```

Printing the elements after the merge will have your value members updated:

```
for e in list_one:
    print(e.date_time,e.name,e.value)

# Output:

2022-01-01 00:00:00 zero 0
2022-01-01 01:00:00 one 1
2022-01-01 02:00:00 two 2
2022-01-01 03:00:00 three 3
```

Your `__init__` function has a lot of duplication in names, that's why it can be a good idea to use [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), it will work the same, but it's easier to read and maintain:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class StructureOne:
    date_time : datetime.datetime
    name : str

@dataclass
class StructureTwo:
    date_time : datetime.datetime
    value : float
```

Comment: The  zip(list_one,list_two) would work if list two only had 2 values insted of 4 ? 
    list_two = [StructureTwo(date_time=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 1), value=1),
    StructureTwo(date_time=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 2), value=2}

Comment: `zip` creates a list of tuples and will have the length of the shorter of the two. You can use the [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=zip_longest#itertools.zip_longest) to fill the remaining elements with a default value.